# Better way to pass bindings into child element in Polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-control/my-control.html" />

<dom-module id="my-page">
   <template>
       <!-- pass the value down to the children element -->
       <my-control my-property="{{myProperty}}"></my-control>
   </template>

   <script>
      Polymer({
         is: 'my-page',

         properties: {
            myProperty: {
               type: String,
               value: '',
               reflectToAttribute: true
            }
         }
      });
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is the "child" control

```
<dom-module id="my-control">
   <template>
       <!-- print the value of the property -->
       <span>{{myProperty}}></span>
   </template>

   <script>
      Polymer({
         is: 'my-control',

         properties: {
            myProperty: {
               type: String,
               value: '',
               reflectToAttribute: true
            }
         }
      });
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

And this is how I use it. I do this because actually `"my-page"` doesn't really need a property but `"my-control"` does and it is contained in the DOM of `"my-page"`. Is there any other way i can do this? Because I am passing a model and I have to deserialize it in attribute by attribute for each property?

```
<link rel="import" href="/my-page/my-page.html" />

<!-- declare parent element and value -->
<my-page my-property="ABCDE-12345"></my-page>
```

Comment: Not really. The only other way i can think of is in js select `my-page` access it's `shadow dom`(method varies in V0 and V1 spec) and then select `my-control` and assign it value.

Comment: I hope for some sort of "parent" data-binding syntax like Angular has but I double checked and I didn't find anything on Polymer 1.x docs

Comment: Nothing of sort exists in Polymer

Answer (score -1):

Your question expresses concern for redeclaring a child property in the parent in order to pass the property through to the child. You actually don't need to redeclare the property in the parent if it's completely unused by the parent (unless the parent's users require two-way data binding on that property).

Below is a declarative example that **omits the property redeclaration** in the parent.

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <my-page foo="123"></my-page>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is: 'x-foo'});
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-page">
  <template>
    <my-element foo="[[foo]]"></my-element>
  </template>
  <script>
    // no property declaration needed for one-way binding
    Polymer({is: 'my-page'});
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vgXwgg?editors=1010)

*Side note:* you don't need to set `reflectToAttribute` for data bindings.

Comment: @Raffaeu I admit it *looks* very similar to what you're already doing, but it's not exactly the same. Your question expressed concern for declaring a property in the parent unnecessarily, and my answer indicates that it's not actually necessary to do that if you're only passing it directly to the child. I added a section to indicate that the redeclaration in the parent would only be needed for two-way binding, and perhaps that clouded the issue, since it's evident that you don't need the property at all in the parent (or the parent's users). I'll update my answer to at least clarify that.